# Fedora 26 and fully qualified domain names?

Tags: fedora, dns, hostname

I installed Fedora 26 for testing under GCC 7. F26 is installed in a 64-bit VirtualBox VM. I ran the following commands to configure the system post-install, and then rebooted:

```
localhost:~$ sudo hostnamectl set-chassis desktop
localhost:~$ sudo hostnamectl set-deployment production
localhost:~$ sudo hostnamectl set-hostname --static --transient --pretty asus-f26-x64.
```

After logon, the hostname is:

```
asus-f26-x64:~$ hostname
asus-f26-x64
```

It appears the fully qualified domain name was ignored. Fully qualified domain names end in dot (`.`), and they signify the top of the DNS tree.  Also see Steven's [TCP/IP Illustrated, Volume I](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/0201633469).

How do I set a fully qualified domain name as the hostname?

A related issue is the host does not register its name with my DHCP server. I don't see an option to send the hostname in the [`hostnameclt` man page](https://www.freedesktop.org/software/systemd/man/hostnamectl.html).

I guess the DHCP name issue is related to the FQDN issue since the machine does not need a name from a DHCP server, but the host does not realize it because the FQDN is being mishandled.

How do I instruct the machine to sends its hostname?

---

Below is from `hostnamectl status`. Things are a little worse because the dot is being interpreted as some sort of adornment for the pretty name; and not being recognized as a FQDN.

```
$ hostnamectl status
   Static hostname: asus-f26-x64
   Pretty hostname: asus-f26-x64.
         Icon name: computer-desktop
           Chassis: desktop
        Deployment: production
        Machine ID: 3d914cf11226f83093acc
           Boot ID: 21fb5dabfd6a0c24ba8f2
    Virtualization: oracle
  Operating System: Fedora 26 (Workstation Edition)
       CPE OS Name: cpe:/o:fedoraproject:fedora:26
            Kernel: Linux 4.11.9-300.fc26.x86_64
      Architecture: x86-64
```

Answer (score 3):

If you look at the `hostnamectl` source code [here](https://github.com/systemd/systemd/blob/179e679edd5c4456da5cf09c230941d620ed4c3a/src/hostname/hostnamectl.c), you will see that `hostnamectl` will use the `set_hostname` function to do the deed.

A comment from that section reads the following (emphasis mine):

> Now that we set the pretty hostname, let's clean up the parameter and use that as static
>   hostname. If the hostname was already valid as static hostname, this will only **chop off the trailing
>   dot** if there is one. If it was not valid, then it will be made fully valid by truncating, dropping
>   multiple dots, and dropping weird chars. Note that we clean the name up only if we also are
>   supposed to set the pretty name. If the pretty name is not being set we assume the user knows what
>   he does and pass the name as-is.

Indeed, if you check the `method_set_static_hostname` [here](https://github.com/systemd/systemd/blob/b4227dbb452003d17877a9b23d191dc5ccc53138/src/hostname/hostnamed.c), where it tries to set the static hostname, the relevant part goes like this:

```
if (!hostname_is_valid(name, false))
    return sd_bus_error_setf(error, SD_BUS_ERROR_INVALID_ARGS, "Invalid static hostname '%s'", name);
```

The function signature of the `hostname_is_valid` function is this:

```
bool hostname_is_valid(const char *s, bool allow_trailing_dot) _pure_;
```

You will see then that `hostname_is_valid` is called with the `allow_trailing_dot` arugment as false - thus systemd and hostnamectl do not allow the trailing dot in the static hostname.

---

EDIT: Well, the systemd discussion on this matter can be found [here](https://github.com/systemd/systemd/pull/730). AFAIK, this works "as intended" - the trailing dot being optional. There are arguments for and against, but I won't go into that here.

So - you cannot do this via the systemd hostnamectl tool,...

However, you could always just add the trailing dot to the file `/etc/hostname` and then that'll even show up in the output of `hostnamectl`.

Of course, should you use `hostnamectl` or any other tool to set the hostname at any point in the future, it will overwrite that.

Comment: Thanks Rabban. How do I work around the issue of not allowing a FQDN? Would you happen to know?

Comment: Thanks again Rabba. Now open in the systemd issue tracker: [Issue 6369, systemd does not honor fully qualified domain names](https://github.com/systemd/systemd/issues/6369).

Answer (score 0):

It is very seldom that tools like this use a (printed) trailing dot (even if it is accepted).
To get a fully qualified name, which should be printed with this:

```
$ hostname -f
asus-f26-x64.example.com
```

You need to make `/etc/resolv.conf` (or equivalent in fedora) to have a domain line:

```
domain example.com.
```

But understand that it is not posible to have a fqdn of just **one** label:

```
asus-f26-x64
```

That could be the name of the computer, one label. But you do need some other label (or labels, text limited by dots) to work as a domain (like example). And as the internet has its own list of [Internet TLD](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_Internet_top-level_domains) that should also be added. Thus, the fqdn must be something like:

```
asus-f26-x64.company.domain.net.
```

Comment: Thanks Arrow. I used my internal domain - `asus-f26-x64.home.pvt.` (`home.pvt` is my internal network name/domain). However, the tools discarded it, too. I really miss the old days when things "just worked".